# Need help with these recurrence relations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I had received some challenging recurrence last week, I did most of them except this and also one of its kind. It states

> Given $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$,  solve these recurrence relations:
>
> - $a_n=a_{n-1}^2+a_{n-2}$
> - $a_n=a_{n-1}^2+a_{n-2}^2$

So, could anybody help me with these recurrences? I have no idea how to proceed it..

Comment: both the recurrence's at the same time or the two are different questions?

Comment: Different That's why I mentioned no 2 there

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580069/recurrence-a-n-sum-k-1n-1a2-k-a-1-1